# Fundamentals to build a reactive application using F# and Datomic

Tags: c#, f#, reactive-programming, datomic

We want to show the capabilities of reactive applications (the context is an academic project). Our goal is to built a project with several application, working with F# and Datomic. The project is composed with the following parts:

- An `event producer`: produces GPS coordinates associated with a timestamp that simulate a human being behavior.
- A first `event listener` connected to a POI (Point Of Interest) database that returns the closest relevant POI. A row is composed of GPS coordinates and 2 timestamps representing opening hours. We can assimilate this application to the real time application behind Gmail that scan the last user's email that speak about snow and display commercials about warm clothes.
- A second `event listener` that saves every user's moves in Datomic.
- (optional) An application that look into Datomic and tries to find relevant information about a user. (Often close to that POI, working hours, and so on)

New to both Datomic and F# (or functional programming), we have a few unanswered questions.

F#:

- What is the best practice for the event producer to produces it's events and be listened by two external applications (running on the same machine for now)? We could use messages but the important point here is that the event producer isn't aware of the listeners.
- Would it be better to use C# for this kind of code (we want the GPS coordinates to seem real so it's basically a few `randoms` and `loops`.

Datomic:

- What is the best way to query datomic from F#? Our point of view is to use [Datomic's REST API](http://docs.datomic.com/rest.html) because we didn't see any other way to do it. Any resources speaking about this subjects to help us figure out how to do it are welcome.
- Is Datomic a good choice for the POI database or should we prefer a good old relational database? So far, the POI table will be raw; meaning we won't do any effort to organize the POI in a grid or a tree to avoid querying the entire database for each processed event. (We know it is bad but for now we just want to make it work, (make it work -> make it right -> make it fast... right?)

Partials answers are welcome. We will compose a complete answer if needed to help future people interested with that subject.

Comment: There's an [F# type provider for Datomic](https://github.com/dmitry-a-morozov/FSharp.Data.Datomic) which should be much simpler than using the REST API.

Comment: For your listening of external events, why not publish your events to an observable, and have a socket listener that acts as a subscriber that `onNext` will write to the socket for any connected client?